# regexp validate csv string in javascript without lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I need to validate with javascript an input entry like csv (without space near commas)
I'using this regexp:

```
^(?! )[A-zÀ-ú\w\s]+(?:(?! )(?! )[A-zÀ-ú\w\s]+)?((?<! ),(?! )[A-zÀ-ú\w\s]+(?:-(?! )[A-zÀ-ú\w\s]+)?)*(?<! )$
```

working fine in chrome but not in firefox (lookbehind not work)

I'm not able to normalize in order to work crossbrowser.

Need to validate user input from textbox 
Sample:word = ok - word,word1 word2 = ok - word ,word1 = ko - ,word = ko - word,accented word àò = ok 
So: no trail space
no rail space
no comma as first or last char

Any help ?
thank you.

Comment: Hi Piero. Welcome to stackoverflow!. Please take the time to re-edit your question and make sure the regular expression you posted doesn't contain syntax errors. Regards.

Comment: ops, thank you, i was lost in code formatting :(

Comment: Can you please post some random data from the csv file? Also, the expected output vs. the output with the problem

Comment: Please edit your question and add the examples to the question, not as a comment